# nice output of file listing in bash

Tags: linux, bash, find, list

I have a script that lists all files in a specific directory and send me a mail once a week.
But i'd like to have a nicer listing than this;

```
folder/subfolder/file1.avi
folder/subfolder/file2.avi
..
folder5/subfolder34/file52.mov
```

Is there an easy way to do this? My bashline today:
`find /volume2/Disk2 -type f \( -iname "*.avi" -o -iname "*.m*v" -o -iname "*.iso" -o -iname "*.mp*" \) | sort -do /tmp/$DATE-filmer.txt`

What I would like is something like this;

```
folder1/
  File1.avi
  File2.mov
Folder4
  Subfolder1
    File12.mov
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this fairly easily with the `tree` command, which is installed by default on many systems or available from most package repositories:

```
$ tree -P "*.mp*|*.avi"
.
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── movie.avi
│   ├── some.avi
│   └── something.mp3
└── zot.mp4
```

Without the filter:

```
$ tree
.
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── movie.avi
│   ├── some.avi
│   ├── something.doc
│   └── something.mp3
├── something.txt
└── zot.mp4
```

Comment: Thanx, It works, but an ugly solution for me... Or is there a way to filter out the lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
export dir=''; export prefix='  ';
find /volume2/Disk2 -type f \( -iname "*.avi" -o -iname "*.m*v" -o -iname "*.iso" -o -iname "*.mp*" \) |
while read file; do \
  if [ ! "$dir" == "$(dirname $file)" ]; then \
    export dir="$(dirname $file)";
    slashes=$(echo "$dir" | sed 's#[^/]##g' | wc -c);
    export prefix='';
    for (( i=1; i<$slashes; i++ )); do \
      export prefix="$prefix  ";
    done;
    echo "$prefix$dir/";
    export prefix="$prefix  ";
  fi;
  echo "$prefix$(basename $file)";
done
```

Sample output snippet on a random CPAN directory for me:

```
  ./.cpan/build/Sub-Uplevel-0.24-GduPEf/
    Makefile
    dist.ini
    META.json
    perlcritic.rc
    README.PATCHING
    META.yml
    Makefile.PL
      ./.cpan/build/Sub-Uplevel-0.24-GduPEf/blib/bin/
        .exists
        ./.cpan/build/Sub-Uplevel-0.24-GduPEf/blib/lib/Sub/
          Uplevel.pm
          .exists
            ./.cpan/build/Sub-Uplevel-0.24-GduPEf/blib/lib/auto/Sub/Uplevel/
              .exists
      ./.cpan/build/Sub-Uplevel-0.24-GduPEf/blib/script/
        .exists
      ./.cpan/build/Sub-Uplevel-0.24-GduPEf/blib/man1/
        .exists
      ./.cpan/build/Sub-Uplevel-0.24-GduPEf/blib/arch/
        .exists
            ./.cpan/build/Sub-Uplevel-0.24-GduPEf/blib/arch/auto/Sub/Uplevel/
              .exists
      ./.cpan/build/Sub-Uplevel-0.24-GduPEf/blib/man3/
        Sub::Uplevel.3pm
        .exists
```

Comment: When trying to use the code above, I keep getting the following error:
BusyBox v1.16.1 (2013-08-17 02:30:39 CST) multi-call binary.

Usage: dirname FILENAME

Strip non-directory suffix from FILENAME

Comment: @user2059446, you're running on BusyBox, which is not Bash.  You'll need to launch a proper Bash shell to get this to work, or else you'll need to rework it for Busybox's syntactical peccadilloes.

Comment: OK. Thanx for your reply, but since it's a Synology Nas with limited settings, I think I have to look for another solution then. :/

Comment: In that case, mount up the share and run this same command from a real Bash.  Even something like Cygwin would work; just map to `F:` and then navigate to `/cygdrive/f`.